# ArcGIS Map hangs when adding Feature Layer

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

When I create map object using `ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer` then things work fine but since I need lot of graphics and want to handle user interactions on map so I want to feature layer to my map but when I add feature layer the browser hangs.

I am using ArcGIS Server 10.1 and ArcGIS JS API 3.6.

How can I avoid the feature layer hanging from my machine?

```
map = new esri.Map("map");
              var layer = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://10.32.9.106:6080/arcgis/rest/services/Administrative_Maps/World_Countries_v1/MapServer");
              map.addLayer(layer);
              var url = "http://10.32.9.106:6080/arcgis/rest/services/Administrative_Maps/World_Countries_v1/MapServer/0";
              var info_content = "<table><tr><td><b>COUNTRY :</b></td><td style='text-align:right'>${COUNTRY}</td></tr></table>";
              var infoTemplate1 = new esri.InfoTemplate("${COUNTRY}", info_content);
              var fl = new esri.layers.FeatureLayer(url, {
                id: "world-regions",
                 outFields: ["COUNTRY"],
                infoTemplate: infoTemplate1
              });
               map.addLayer(fl);
```

When i see in net panel of my firebug i see some of request being timeout and aborted like below once

```
http://10.32.9.106:6080/arcgis/rest/services/Administrative_Maps/World_Countries_v1/MapServer/0/query?f=json&returnGeometry=true&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&maxAllowableOffset=0&geometry=%7B%22xmin%22%3A-180%2C%22ymin%22%3A-26.69003668516953%2C%22xmax%22%3A85.04864429221129%2C%22ymax%22%3A238.35860760704176%2C%22spatialReference%22%3A%7B%22wkid%22%3A4326%2C%22latestWkid%22%3A4326%7D%7D&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=4326&outFields=COUNTRY%2CFID&outSR=4326
```

The issue may be something to do with lot of graphics of feature layer that browse has to fetch.  Otherwise, it may be related to query feature of feature layer. When I tried to query using rest url I added COUNTRY='Australia' and I got a result immediately.

I tried setting autoGeneralize as enable but still no help.

Below is the output of rest service [http://10.32.9.106:6080/arcgis/rest/services/Administrative_Maps/World_Countries_v1/MapServer/0][1]

```
Name: World_Countries_v3 

Display Field: COUNTRY 

Type: Feature Layer 

Geometry Type: esriGeometryPolygon 

Description: World Countires Map (v3) with the Display field as ISO3A. No changes to the data from V1. 

Definition Expression: 

Copyright Text: 

Default Visibility: true 

MaxRecordCount: 1000

Supported Query Formats: JSON, AMF

Min Scale: 0

Max Scale: 0

Supports Advanced Queries: false

Supports Statistics: false

Has Labels: false

Can Modify Layer: true

Can Scale Symbols: false

Extent:
XMin: -179.99999999990004
YMin: -89.99999999990001
XMax: 180.00000000010002
YMax: 83.66549107605236
Spatial Reference: 4326  (4326) 


Drawing Info:
Renderer:
Simple Renderer:
Symbol:
Style: esriSFSSolid 
Color: [206, 191, 242, 255] 
Outline:
Style: esriSLSSolid 
Color: [110, 110, 110, 255] 
Width: 0
Label: 
Description:
Transparency: 0 
Labeling Info:

HasZ: false 

HasM: false 

Has Attachments: false 

HTML Popup Type: esriServerHTMLPopupTypeAsHTMLText 

Type ID Field: null

Fields:
FID ( type: esriFieldTypeOID , alias: FID )
Shape ( type: esriFieldTypeGeometry , alias: Shape )
OBJECTID ( type: esriFieldTypeInteger , alias: OBJECTID )
COUNTRY ( type: esriFieldTypeString , alias: COUNTRY , length: 50 )
CONTINENT ( type: esriFieldTypeString , alias: CONTINENT , length: 13 )
ISO3A ( type: esriFieldTypeString , alias: ISO3A , length: 5 )
ISO2 ( type: esriFieldTypeString , alias: ISO2 , length: 5 )
Shape_Leng ( type: esriFieldTypeDouble , alias: Shape_Leng )
Shape_Area ( type: esriFieldTypeDouble , alias: Shape_Area )

Supported Operations:   Query   Generate Renderer   Return Updates
```

Answer (score -1):

This blog addresses your issue: [High performance web apps with big datasets as feature layers](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/06/29/high-performance-web-apps-with-big-datasets-as-feature-layers/)